# NSURLConnection timeout?

Tags: iphone, timeout, nsurlconnection

I'm using this NSURLConnection with delegates.

```
nsconnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request
    delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

Problem is the website doesn't respond at all. Nothing, just spins in browser with blank page, no failure. In my delegates, I handle the failure, but when the site doesn't respond the delegates don't get called. Any ideas on how to timeout the connection?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You can specify a timeout in your `NSURLRequest` object.  One way to do this is to construct it via the [`requestWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest/1528579-requestwithurl) method.  (You can pass in the default `NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy` cachePolicy parameter if you don't want to worry about that part.)  The timeout is a floating-point value in seconds, as are basically all time intervals in the iPhone SDK.

Also make sure your `NSURLConnection`'s delegate is set and responds to the [`connection:didFailWithError:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlconnectiondelegate/1418443-connection?language=objc) method.  A connection always calls either this method or `connectionDidFinishLoading:` upon connection completion.

Comment: The delegate does work and does respond when an error is sent by the web server. In this case the webserver sends nothing. Just spins. I configure the request method to add the timeout. Thanks

Comment: If you want to try an alternative to NSURLStuff, a friend of mine recommended ASIHTTPRequest (google it) which is free to use, and looks pretty friendly, including timeout functionality.

Comment: fyi, default is 60 seconds.

Comment: If i put flight mode while http call with server. how do i know request failed ? any completion block?

Answer (score 24):

**Edit:** This answer is now obsolete, but at the date of answering was accurate.

I know this thread is old, but I ran into this issue as well. This happened when testing the app outside the internal network where the services lived. The service will eventually timeout, but Apple mandates a period of 240 seconds (4 minutes) before the time out occurs. Check out this thread for more info on the matter.

[NSMutableURLRequest not obeying my timeoutInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736967/nsmutableurlrequest-not-obeying-my-timeoutinterval)

Comment: I believe I fixed this by add NSCredentials to my Application. The non responsiveness was due to the server requesting authentication, which I wasn't providing.

Comment: That's wrong information! According to http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLRequest the default timeout interval is 60 seconds.

Comment: @stigi it looks like you're referencing material for Mac OS whereas ezekielDFM is talking about iOS.

Comment: @leukosaima The documentation for the iOS version of `NSUrlRequest` (just replace 'mac' with 'ios' in the URL) also states that the default is 60 seconds (although I don't know whether this was the case at the time that stigi and you posted, nor whether what the documentation claims was/is actually true).

Comment: -1; this answer is indeed obsolete. The 240 second minimum value for the `timeoutInterval` property is no longer in place.