# How to cancel web service call - IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, nsurlconnection

I have user authentication in my iPhone application. User login works in a way that application send username/password to web service for user check. The problem I have now is I don't know how to setup 'timeout' (30 seconds) and stop requesting data from web service?

```
NSString *soapMsg = 
    [NSString stringWithFormat:
     @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>...", username, password
     ];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://...Service.asmx"];      

    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];    
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMsg length]];

    [req addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];   
    [req addValue:@"http://.../LoginUser" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];    
    [req addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];   
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [req setHTTPBody: [soapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];

    if (conn) 
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[req setTimeoutInterval:urInterval];
```

> ```
> setTimeoutInterval:
> ```
>
> Sets the receiver’s timeout interval, in seconds.
>
> `- (void)setTimeoutInterval:(NSTimeInterval)timeoutInterval`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> timeoutInterval
>
> ```
> The timeout interval, in seconds. If during a connection attempt
> ```
>
> the request remains idle for longer than the timeout interval, the
>   request is considered to have timed out. The default timeout interval
>   is 60 seconds.

Comment: I added '[req setTimeoutInterval:30];'. And now if request is time out where is the handler for this? Is it '-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didFailWithError:(NSError *) error '?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cancel method of the NSURLConnection

```
/*! 
    @method cancel
    @abstract Cancels an asynchronous load of a URL.
    @discussion Once this method is called, the asynchronous load is
    stopped, and the NSURLConnectionDelegate associated with the
    receiver will no longer receive any asynchronous callbacks for
    this NSURLConnection.
*/
- (void)cancel;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [ASIHTTP](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) might help you?

Also, if I understood you correctly, a mostly [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046417/iphone-web-service-request-timeout) on stackoverflow.