# NSMutableURLRequest setTimeoutInterval issue

Tags: iphone, nsmutableurlrequest

Ok firstly if I use a NSURLReuqest(non mutable) as following, the the connection do timeout accordingly to what was set.
The weird thing is why does the NSLog always read 0?

```
self.requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestString]cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:20.0];
NSLog(@"request timeOutInterval:%d", self.requestURL.timeoutInterval); // always 0
```

Next, I do something like this and the timeoutInterval does not get set.

```
self.requestURL = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestString]] autorelease];
[self.requestURL setTimeoutInterval:20];
NSLog(@"request timeOutInterval:%i", self.requestURL.timeoutInterval); // same thing always 0 here.
```

EDIT. I am using %f to log the timeoutInterval property now and both reads 20.000. But the real problem is why was my my NSMutableURLRequest not firing the `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error` delegate call back method when it reaches the timeoutInterval(20s). Instead it is only timed out at around the 75s. Even longer than the default of 60s...

Even if I remove the `[self.requestURL setTimeoutInterval:20];` line, the connection still timeout at 75s.

I have tried

`self.requestURL = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:20.0] autorelease];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

`NSLog(@"request timeOutInterval:%f", self.requestURL.timeoutInterval);` It worked for me.

**UPDATE**

Check this answer by @Francois in this previous [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736967/nsmutableurlrequest-not-obeying-my-timeoutinterval)

> There's a thread on Apple dev forums discussing this issue. Apparently
>   on iPhone OS, the setter mandates timeoutInterval a minimum of 240
>   seconds (4 minutes). This only occurs when the postBody is not empty
>   (typically when using a POST request). This seems crazy, but
>   apparently it's there to make sure requests leave the system even
>   though it might take many seconds for the WWAN (3G) interface to wake
>   up. 240 seconds seems rather steep, so they suggest to set a timer and
>   cancel the asynchronous connection when your timer fires. I know this
>   seems stupid, but that's the only I managed to get timeout for POST
>   requests...

Comment: I see, I was using the POST method. But it times out at 75s instead of the stated 240. I wonder why did Apple enforced that...

Comment: Not sure. But I prefer ASIHTTPRequest. Its much better.

Answer (score 0):

Your `NSLog` statement uses a `%d` format specifier, which indicates an integer, but the `timeoutInterval` property is a double.

Try using `%f` instead, which indicates you want to log a double value.

Comment: @Ok, both NSLogs now reads 20.0000. But the real problem is why was my  my NSMutableURLRequest not firing the `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
` delegate call back method when it reaches the timeoutInterval(20s). Instead it is only timed out at around the 75s. Even longer then the default of 60s...

Answer (score 0):

Use `%f`, `NSTimeInterval` is floating point number.

```
Refer Foundation data types ref:
NSTimeInterval
Used to specify a time interval, in seconds.
typedef double NSTimeInterval;
```

Answer (score 0):

it work for me:

```
NSLog(@"request timeOutInterval:%@", requestURL.timeoutInterval);
```