# Implement Timeout in HTTP Post

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, http-post

What is the best way to implement a connection timeout (let's say, 20 seconds) within an HTTP post connection?

My current code is as follows:

```
-(NSData*) postData: (NSString*) strData
{    
    //postString is the STRING TO BE POSTED
    NSString *postString;

    //this is the string to send
    postString = @"data=";
    postString = [postString stringByAppendingString:strData]; 

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"MYSERVERHERE"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postString length]];

    //setting prarameters of the POST connection
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request addValue:@"en-US" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Language"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:10.0];

    NSLog(@"%@",postString);

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;

    NSLog(@"Starting the send!");
    //this sends the information away. everybody wave!
    NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Just finished receiving!");
    if (&error) //OR TIMEOUT
    {
        NSLog(@"ERROR!");
        NSString *errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ERROR"];
        urlData = [errorString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }
    return urlData;
}
```

Obviously the timeout interval is set to 10.0, but nothing seems to happen when those ten seconds hit.

Comment: have you implemented the `NSURLConnection` delegate methods?

Comment: Looking through the delegate methods, I do not see one that mentions timeout. connection:didReceiveResponse:, connection:didReceiveData:, connection:didFailWithError: and connectionDidFinishLoading:.

Comment: Well, `connection:didFailWithError` will be called when the request hits the timeout

Comment: Take a look at this question though, it's about post requests http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736967/nsmutableurlrequest-not-obeying-my-timeoutinterval

Comment: Looking through the apple docs though, they show a timeout of 60 which, of course, does not hit their minimum interval of 240. What are your thoughts?http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

Comment: Test it and see if its 60 or 240 secs. If you need a shorter timeout, do as the question i linked to says and set a timer. When it expires, close the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

[NSMutableURLRequest timeout interval not taken into consideration for POST requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466389/nsmutableurlrequest-timeout-interval-not-taken-into-consideration-for-post-reques)

Apparently timeouts under 240 seconds are ignored.  The highest voted answer in that question links to a solution.  However, I would simply recommend using the ASIHTTPRequest library instead.

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: Yet looking through Apples documents, in their sample code they use a timeout of 60. I'm quite confused.