# How can i set connection timeout to NSUrlConnection

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsurlconnection

I know there is a setTimeoutInterval method to NSMutableURLRequest, but can i set a specific timeout to the time it takes to reach and connect to the server?

Comment: plese refere here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889060/what-is-the-situation-regarding-the-nsurlconnection-timeout-with-ios5

Comment: I am not sure i understand from this question what is the timeout interval referring to.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. Timeout is the time by which we expect the reply from server. We have no idea what time had gone to connect to server and what time for the server to reply.

Answer (score 1):

A `NSURLConnection` will abort the connection with a timeout error if the connection is "idle" for longer than the specified duration set via `setTimeoutInterval`.

That means, if you start a request and the client did not receive anything from the server so far, you should get a timeout error in `connection:didFailWithError:` after that duration.

That also means, if you are in the middle of a connection sending/receiving data, and the server later hangs and the connection becomes "idle" for longer than the specified timeout, it will also abort the connection.

Whenever the connection has some progress, the timer will be reset.

You can tweak that behavior in so far that you start your own timer which sends `cancel` to the connection after a specific duration. Possibly you may monitor the progress and estimate how long the request will take to finish and then possibly invoke the cancel if that will take to long.