# Handling time out with NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: ios, post, connection-timeout, nsmutableurlrequest

I am making POST web service calls in parallel which are asynchronous, setting the time interval of `NSMutableURLRequest` to 180 seconds.

But my `didFailWithError:` delegate is not getting triggered  exactly at the interval of 180 seconds, rather it goes too less to 75 seconds or too greater value to 220 seconds and so on, but not once for 180 seconds.

As far I scanned through the similar questions, there is no solid solution for this. But at much places, I could see like `timeOutInterval` will not work for POST methods. 
I just want to know whether this issue is true with POST methods and Is there any way to overcome this at least in iOS8?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using POST and an iOS version bellow 6, you have to set a value above 240 seconds. Otherwise, your timeout will be ignored. See [this post](https://devforums.apple.com/message/108087#108087%23108087) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466389/nsmutableurlrequest-timeout-interval-not-taken-into-consideration-for-post-reque).

Comment: My ios version is 7.1.1. After ios6 the default time out is 60 seconds, so i just want to know why the behaviour goes like this or is it a kind of Apple's issue.

Comment: It seems to be an Apple issue. But you could [use a timer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718256/nsurlrequest-timeout-ios)

Comment: ya, i could see all the posts saying this for ios7 too, so i just want to know whether this persists in ios8 too.