# Json Crash the application when i close the Server

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, xcode6

I'm developing an application, and I'm getting the data of JSON from the Database using MAMP PRO for now. This is the Code:

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.8/ArabLineDatabase/GetSocialNetworkCount.php"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30];

 NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.8/ArabLineDatabase/GetSocialNetworkCount.php"]];

  JsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if (connection)
    {
        NSLog(@"Connecting.....GetSocialNetworkCount.M");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Can't connect.....GetSocialNetworkCount.M");
    }
```

The problem is whenever there is no internet or i close the server so it will not be reachable my application crash, and i get an error that the `JSON Data is nil` How i can prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to cancel your request after a certain time interval, in case the server isn't responding or you don't have a network or something similar.

```
[connection cancel];
```

[This will solve your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718256/nsurlrequest-timeout-ios)