# How to set a timer like event handler and stop the timer on a condition

Tags: jquery

I have a javascript code that generates some elements on the page.But since the data of these newly generated elements comes from an external source,it may take a while for these elements to load.
The thing I want to do is that I want to do some things AFTER these elements are loaded.So I decided I should check if the elements have appeared yet every second and then execute my other coeds.

this is what I want to do:

```
//start a timer like event handler which occurs every second
//in every second{
    if ($(".elementthatmustappear").is(":visible"))
    {
        //stop the timer
        //execute other codes
    }
    else
    {
        //don't stop the timer.continue checking
    }
}
```

is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of: [How to stop a setTimeout loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443151/how-to-stop-a-settimeout-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`The thing I want to do is that I want to do some things AFTER these elements are loaded.`

In this situation it sounds like you should pass a callback to the function loading the content, which should be executed after the load.

If you do decide you want to follow the logic you've mapped out, this should work:

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if ($(".elementthatmustappear").is(":visible")) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        doSomethingElse()
    }
}, 1000);
```