# How to stop a JQuery.load'ed inner scripts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm developing a dynamic web page with nested pages. Inner pages have their own script to be live and modular.

The problem comes when i want to remove one of the inner pages. Infact the HTML code is removed but the inner script keeps running.

Is it possible to stop the script?

This is a brief view of my solution:

*Note that in this sample the ID are all the same but in the real solution they are identified by unique ID using php GET["ID"] value.*

**outerPage.php**

```
<HEAD>
    <script>
    var fRunUpdate = true;
        $(document).ready(function() {

           $("#inner1").load("inner.php");
           $("#inner2").load("inner.php");
           $("#inner3").load("inner.php");

        }
    </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <div id="inner1"></div>
    <div id="inner2"></div>
    <div id="inner3"></div>
</BODY>
```

**innerPage.php**

```
<HEAD>
    <script>
    var fRunUpdate = true;
        $(document).ready(function() {
           function update(){
               //do something
               $("#contentToUpdate").html("content");
               setTimeout(update,1000);
           }
        }
    </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <div id="contentToUpdate"></div>
</BODY>
```

Comment: Where is the code to remove your inner page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use **stoptimeout** or **clear interval**
I just read out this link and get it

[How to stop a setTimeout loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443151/how-to-stop-a-settimeout-loop)

Take function in variable

```
foo = setTimeout(function, time);
```

and then just clear it out

```
clearTimeout(foo);
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: Yes but since foo is declared in a inner scope, how do i access this variable in the outer page?

Comment: YOu can have a global variable in javascript

Comment: It is a good idea but unfortunately doesn' apply to my case. I got a lot of inner pages so i will have a lot of global variables and the code would be messed...

Comment: So you need custom right? you will have to do serialization you can not hide 5 textboxes at a time