# How to stop an Multiple SetInterval in Angular based Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

```
myApp.run(function ($rootScope, $interval, $timeout, $state, $localStorage) {

    load = function () { 
            cdreset(); // reset the countdown to 0
            countdown(); // call the countdown function 
     $rootScope.stayLogin = function () {
            cdreset(); // reset the countdown to 0
             
            alert("Proceed functioncall");

            window.NewTimerCalC = function () { alert('trisssssgered'); return false; };
            NewTimerCalCProceed();          
        };
    
    }
      
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, $rootScope, $state, $location) {
    
        NewTimerCalC();  
    });
    
  
    }); // end of run block
    

function NewTimerCalC(){
    var lastDigestRun = Date.now();
    var s = lastDigestRun + 2 * 60 * 1000;
  
  
    var idleCheck = setInterval(function () {
        if (currentUrl != window.location.href) {
            var now = Date.now();
            var displaytime = now - lastDigestRun > 2 * 60 * 1000;
            if (now - lastDigestRun > 1 * 60 * 1000) {
                alert("run block interval alert");
                //clearTimeout(timeclear);
                load();
            }
        }
    }, 60 * 1000);

}


// button click for staylogin.
function NewTimerCalCProceed() {
window.NewTimerCalC = function () { alert('trisssssgered'); return false; };
    
    
    var lastDigestRun = Date.now();
    var s = lastDigestRun + 2 * 60 * 1000;
   
    var idleCheck = setInterval(function () {
        if (currentUrl != window.location.href) {
            var now = Date.now();
            var displaytime = now - lastDigestRun > 2 * 60 * 1000;
            if (now - lastDigestRun > 1 * 60 * 1000) {
                alert("Proceed block interval alert");
               
                load();
            }
        }
    }, 60 * 1000);

}
```

when user login into the app, i have set the logout time as 2 minutes.
Before 1 minutes, there is a 60 seconds countdown proceessed.
when it reaches 0 seconds, redirect to login page.

InBetween the counter 60 to 1 seconds , if he clicks the proceed ,again 2 minutes need to be assigned for the current user.

Working as expected.

For the first time , user login into the app, the user get 2 minutes as logout time.
Before 1 minutes he gets an warning box and countdown.
there is a proceed button.when user clicks the proceed button, he is getting another 2 minutes.
Before 1 minute he gets an warning message. as expected.

Problem.For the first time it working fine , the problem occur when click the proceed .

the countdown is running, when countdown reaches some seconds for example 30 seconds, another interval process running and reassign the time as 60 seconds.
if user not clicking anything, the countdown reassign again and again.it is not reaching 0 seconds.

here the countdown reaches 35 secons again assigned to 60 seconds because of multiple interval.

[image]
[image]

Comment: why does it look like a task from my PM? Try to reduce the amount of code and description, find the specific place where the problem occurs. Or even if it is too hard, create a plunkr which reproduces the problem

Comment: For more information on how to debug your program, see [How to debug small programs.](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to debug your code.  You show some calls to functions, notably `cdreset()`, which probably have something to do with the problem, but you aren't showing the code for them.

Comment: @Claies,there are 2 Fns not exposed in abovecode,one is countdown and other is cdreset , it is for reset the countdown. In my case, problem is with Setinterval Fn,one interval Fn inside ui-router for tracking the user,when it reaches 1 second, the pop up will open,when  click the proceed button,there is also interval function,again 2 seconds added,before 1 minute countdown running,it reaches some seconds, ui router base interval function trigrd,will show the countdown,at that time proceed block interval call triggered and load the counter. Better i will create demo the project in git hub.

Comment: in angular, using `window` is very abnormal, and you should consider using `$interval` instead of `setInterval`.  `$interval` is a wrapper around `setInterval` that returns a promise, which is easily cancelled.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval#!/

Comment: @Claies If i using $interval something gets wrong in the timer counting Still i  am not able to clear the interval something wrong in the approach if interest pls look here     
 https://github.com/MohamedSahir/UserSession