# Exit setTimeout loop within AJAX GET request

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have a function that performs an AJAX GET request every 1 second to retrieve data and update a progress bar. I'm using `setTimeout` to accomplish this. Here is the code:

```js
function check_progress(thread_id) {
    function worker() {
        $.get('ecab_run/progress/' + thread_id, function(data) {
            progress = data['progress'];
            status_message = data['status_message'];
            if (progress < 100) {
                $('.progress-bar').css('width', progress+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', progress);
                $('.progress-bar')[0].innerHTML = progress+"%";
                $('#status-message')[0].innerHTML = status_message
                timer = setTimeout(worker, 1000);
                // console.log(timer);
            } else if ( progress == 100 ){
              $('.progress-bar').css('width', progress+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', progress);
              $('.progress-bar')[0].innerHTML = progress+"%";
            }
        })
        return status_message;
    }
    worker();
}
```

The function is called after a successful POST as such:

```js
$('#ecab-run-dates').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = $('form').serialize();

  $.ajax({
    url:'',
    type:'post',
    data:formData,
    success:function(data){
      thread_id = data;
      $('.progress-container').show();
      check_progress(thread_id);
      }
    });
  });
```

The backend returns status messages as the behind-the-scenes functions execute, and when it encounters an error, it returns `Error: could not compile data` or something similar.

**My initial thought** was to use the error message as a condition for stopping the `check_progress` function. I've read several answers, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443151/how-to-stop-a-settimeout-loop) one that say to use `clearTimeout`, but I'm not exactly sure how to structure that in my code. Can someone help me exit the `setTimeout` loop when encountering an error?

Comment: You could just check for an error in `check_progress` and return before `setTimeout` is used to queue up another call to the `worker`

Comment: @user1538301 wow can't believe I missed that -- worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? I understand the solution was fairly simple but I hardly think the effort and content of this question is worthy of a downvote?

Comment: I'm not sure. I went ahead and gave it an upvote, but more than likely its because the actual solution was that you needed a break :) I'm sure if you ran for coffee and took a second look at it you'd have come up with a similar solution shortly after.