# How do I "clear" my timer using my clear button?

Tags: javascript, timer

I am new to  javascript. I am trying to clear my timer value on clcking the"clear" button.I tried to use the variable"sec" from myTimer function, but it is not working. Any suggestions? Help is appreciated.

Comment: Plese [edit] your question to show what research you've done and any attempts you've made yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop a setTimeout loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443151/how-to-stop-a-settimeout-loop)

Answer (score 0):

```
let count = 0
let myTimer;

// set timer
myTimer = setInterval(() => count = count + 1 , 1000)

// clear timer
clearInterval(myTimer)
```

Show the code of your timer so that I can describe the solution in more detail

Comment: Questions like these are asked very frequently on Stack Overflow. As such, it's better to find the initial question and mark this question as a duplicate of that original one.

Comment: Here is my timer code:var sec = 5;

var timerID;

document.getElementById("b1").onclick =function(){
    timerID =setInterval(myTimer,1000);
};


function myTimer() {

    document.getElementById("b1").onclick = function() {  
myTimer()  
}  

    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = sec + "sec.";
    sec--;
    if (sec <= -1) {
        clearInterval(timerID);
       
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Time's Up!";

       

}


}

Answer (score 0):

the document.getElementsByTagName gets the button and runs the function when clicked.

```
let timer;
let increment = 0;

timer = setInterval(() => increment++ , 1000)

//gets the button element and clears timer when clicked
document.getElementsByTagName("button").onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(timer)
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).