# Creating Chat function in iOS - Through continuous request

Tags: objective-c, ios, chat

I was tasked to create a Chat function for our app in iOS. I found this tutorial which creates a Chat app from scratch.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-ioschat/index.html

The link above is very helpful, but there is a small problem. In the app, a request will be made every 5 seconds to look for new responses. One of my colleagues said that it is not advisable to make a request to the server every now and then.

So I decided to look for other alternatives. I learned about **long-polling** through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300756/long-polling-in-objective-c).

From what I understood, once a request was made the server will "hold" the request until something interesting comes up. Does this mean that once a response was thrown to the user, the request ends? If that's true, this means that a request will be made every now and then as well, right?

If that's the case, can anyone tell me what's the best way to implement a chat function in iOS?

My friend showed me a <strike>AJAX</strike> JavaScript code (I just found out that he also used a plug-in, which I am not familiar with) where a single continuous request was made, and this request doesn't end even if a response was already thrown to the user. Is there a way to do this in iOS?

Comment: My friend showed me an AJAX code where a single continuous request was made, and this request doesn't end even if a response was already thrown to the user. Is there a way to do this in iOS?
it is possible. show us the code, there might be something special?

Comment: Alright, but he's not yet around so I'll show it later.

Comment: One more thing, the problem in iOS is that requests had time-outs. That's why I thought it was impossible to perform one continuous request in iOS. Hopefully I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good approach to make http ajax request to send and receive chat. A chat response should be displayed at the moment when the other user press "Send". We cant ask for the users to wait 1 second to fetch if there any new responses.

You must use a chat server to accomplish this. I hope the following url would be helpful. I just wanted to give you the Idea of using a Chat Server.

[http://wiki.remobjects.com/wiki/SuperHTTP_Chat_(iOS)*Sample*(Xcode)](http://wiki.remobjects.com/wiki/SuperHTTP_Chat_%28iOS%29_Sample_%28Xcode%29)

Comment: Hi. I will check this out and see if it will help. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think we will be able to use a Chat server. Honestly I was almost done with the feature. I was just looking for the best way to implement it.