# How to call Web service Continuously in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services

I have an ios app.

In which i have multi user account.So multiple user can Login.

When one user see other user profile and if that user is also online i want to notify him.

I can't get how to implement it.

If i have to continuously check some flag value on server if someone has checked their profile or how can i handle it?

Comment: Currently what are doing with your App?

Comment: Currently I had already implemented Multi user Login,Database and the other Funcnality. BUt i stick in this Funcnality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Remote notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html) is the way to do it. The logic on when and who has to be notified can be handled at the server.

You may have seen lots of apps asking for permissions to send notification. The downside being if the user denies that permission.

[Polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300756/long-polling-in-objective-c) from client side can also be one of the methods which can be used and but would require the client to do most of the computation.

So all in all, its a call you got to take considering what you are building.

Comment: I am thinking if the other user is already i have to make him aware by  Alertview

Comment: In that case you can go with polling which is as reliable as the server you will be contacting for details.

Comment: Do you have your webservice running? In that case the link to the question i have in my answer is a good start point. If you don't have the webservice running, then time to ask another SO question probably in the php/RoR tags. I think you can have a basic webservice up and running in less than 2 hours. Search for MAMP/LAMP/WAMP or basic installation of RoR aka Ruby on Rails.