# refresh app after item added in java web services method

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, tomcat

I want to refresh my application whenever a new item is added, and object is added to *database*. However my tables *are not* updated, And I need to refresh my page to see the items. My front end is IOS and back end is java web services for integration. So, Now I want to add one method to refresh my mobile application.

Comment: hey share the code, pls.

Comment: i want to develop the code could you just suggest me thats it.

Comment: k, if you want the instructions for how to create that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement some form of push notification. [(Push Notification)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)
You could do this using long polling or using Apple Push notification services.  See these.

[long polling in objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300756/long-polling-in-objective-c)

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1