# How to implement message delivered notification iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I am developing a messaging application for iOS where I want to show message delivered and read by the user status on the app. I have to achieve this is two phase. phase one is like whatsapp. the app will show one tick mark when delivered to the server and two tick mark when the message is sent to the destination from the server.

In phase two i have to implement the functionality like iMessage or BBM. Where the Read status has to be shown only when the message is read by the user.

I proposed that I can send push notifications from both end but that doesnt sound like a proper solution to me. So seeking the experts advice here.

Comment: have you tried something before posting the question here ? try google, you will find too many tutorials & references for it.

Comment: @pawan yes I googled and most of the articles were talking about xmpp and mqtt etc. But I am not using any of these servers. I was looking for an option around push notification and as Zigglzworth mentioned looks like push notifications isnt correct way to implement what I wanted to achieve. hence my post in SO

Answer (score 1):

Sending a PUSH to confirm on the receivers end that a message was delivered is incorrect.

You could implement a long-polling technique as described here : 
[long polling in objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300756/long-polling-in-objective-c)

Also, look at this article regarding using WebSockets in iOS natively to achieve similar things:
http://www.elabs.se/blog/66-using-websockets-in-native-ios-and-android-apps

Answer (score -1):

[Here is a full tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) for all thinks you need, it has two parts, complete them both, and you will have a fully working push app.

Comment: This does NOT address the question asked. Please read @Tamil's question before you answer.