# Adding A TimeOut?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, xcode4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSURLConnection timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424608/nsurlconnection-timeout)

I have this code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://some-url-that-has-to-work/"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
        returningResponse:&response error:NULL];
    return (response != nil);
```

Is there a way to add a timeout so if the request takes more then 1 minute it just times out?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). It's a wrapper for common network connections for iOS. It has everything you need, including timeout and multiple connection attempts in case of failures.  http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

You can set a global timeout as such:

```
   [ASIHTTPRequest setDefaultTimeOutSeconds:5];
```

and then call the URL:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www......."];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

you have delegate functions that you can use when you get a timeout (or the response)

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
// this is called if the request is successful
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
// this is called if the request fails
}
```

Comment: ASI is a lot of bloat to add to your project just to be able to set the timeout policy when NSURLConnection does the job just fine.

Comment: @aporat no point in switching to `ASIHTTPRequest` just for setting timeout. Infact underlying ASIHTTPRequest is `NSURLConnection` !