# Maintaining persistent connection with HTTP server so as to get continuous stream

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection, afnetworking

this is the procedure of requirement.

1) I make a request, which will make a connection. It might break, but should be notified to programmer by callback.

2) the data comes as a stream from endless page in chunks.

3) I want suggestion because normal NSURLConnection wont be handy as it will break in no time.
Input here is endless page from which stream comes.

Note: Endless stream might be empty and asynchronous.
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "it will break in no time". Explain this please. NSURLConnection should work fine with a chunked-encoded stream.

Comment: I mean, lets say I am not getting data for 10 mins, it will stop getting. Sorry, if I am wrong. But my stream input might be empty, but whenever data is available it(connection) should get that chunk.

Answer (score 2):

If your only problem is the timeout associated with `NSURLConnection`, you can change that timeout as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424608/nsurlconnection-timeout).

Otherwise, you will have to write your own `NSStream`-based implementation. See [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/NetworkStreams.html) for more information.

Comment: For such streams host is of the format **`http:www.google.com`** and port 80. But for me url is **`http:website.com:30/events?after=1002929`**. How to handle this? Thanks.

Comment: @Mike Weller i want to maintain a persistent channel with http server, Do i need to use NSStream , can you please give any example based on post request? or what do you suggest. i am very new to this IOS  development. Please guide me