# NSURL Request? Registration and Login

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

Here is my code:

```
//login method
- (int) authenticateClient {
NSString *loginWeb = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"http://192.168.118.1/login.php?uname=%@&pass=%@&submit=Log%%20In"), user, pass];
NSURL *login = [NSURL URLWithString:loginWeb];
NSData *loginData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: login];
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:loginData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *loginRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[loginRequest setURL:login];
[loginRequest setTimeoutInterval:1];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:loginRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
[connection start];
   return [result integerValue];
}
```

My question is, when simulating having no network connection, my app freezes up and doesn't load or time out in the specified interval (1 second just to see if it works).

I read something about start immediately forces in to run on the current threat causing everything else to "pause" until the action is complete.

I have two questions:

1.) What is a better method to have the URL basically run in the background instead of pausing everything?

2.) How can I get a timeout method that actually works?

Much appreciation! Thanks!

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You have two lumps of code that both try to achieve the same thing. And there is no need to `-start` an `NSURLConnection` when it's already started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one second as timeout is really low. If you want to simulate different network conditions, you can use something like [this](http://mschrag.github.com/). You don't need to this dance:

```
NSData *loginData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: login];
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:loginData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

You don't need this as well, since the connection has started already:

```
[connection start];
```

Also from the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> NSURLConnection’s delegate methods—defined by the
>   NSURLConnectionDelegate Protocol protocol—allow an object to receive
>   informational callbacks about the asynchronous load of a URL request.
>   Other delegate methods provide facilities that allow the delegate to
>   customize the process of performing an asynchronous URL load. These
>   delegate methods are called on the thread that started the
>   asynchronous load operation for the associated NSURLConnection object.

So for your questions:

- Implement the `NSURLConnection’s` delegate
- Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424608/nsurlconnection-timeout) & [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE).

Comment: I hate to say it, but I don't fully understand this answer... 

Is there a way you can show me an example in code? My app still freezes if a connection cannot be made, and the default/minimum timeout method is 240 seconds (so 1 second is irrelevant unfortunately). I don't want the user to have to wait 4 minutes for the method to timeout, and I can't use a countdown timer if the thread freezes until the connection method returns either successful or not. :(