# Preventing http time outs

Tags: java, rest, http

I've a .net client application through which I'm making a REST API(written in Java) on click of a button.

The REST API internally calls a long running task(which takes more than one hour to complete) on the server. On invoking this from .net client, the http request gets timed out.

Just wondering how to prevent this issue? Do I need to increase the timeout value or would a KEEP-ALIVE setting suffice?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: For long-running tasks, it is better to have the API just kick off the task and return some kind of JobId. You would check on the result using a different method (another API to periodically poll, or receive the results via a push notification).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36888095/in-a-restful-web-service-is-it-acceptable-for-the-server-to-take-many-minutes-t?noredirect=1&lq=1