# Set a timeout for a slow network connection in iOS?

Tags: ios, json, connectivity

I have a JSON database connection for my app, and it is set to load (refresh) on the app's initial launch. The JSON data is stored on the phone, and retrievable if no internet connection is discovered on relaunching the app--so there's always data in there.

If the user has a slow connection to the internet--as in patchy <3G--the app will hang. I would like to set a timeout that reverts the database to the saved information (as it would if there were no connection at all). Unfortunately, I think that setting the timeout in the wrong function could make the app crash.

I've read there's no publicly available class to determine a connection speed, but can anyone suggest alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

You could set a timeout for the NSURLRequest, if thats what you're using. In the callback that handles the timeout you could fall back to your local copy of the data. Check the following answer provided by another user.

- [NSURLConnection timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424608/nsurlconnection-timeout)

If you wanted to determine the actual connection speed, you could have your app download a piece of arbitrary data of fixed length, and record the time it takes to complete. This has its own flaws though. You would have to decide when to do this, and how frequently. It may also suffer from the problem that you are trying to solve. And, for example, if the user was on a train, their connection may be great one moment, and poor the next. I think that the timeout solution would work ok, it just means that the user has to wait a period of time before the app falls back to the local copy of the data.